# Asymptotic limit of the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am interested in the asymptotic limit of the following integral for $a\rightarrow\infty$, 
$$\int_0^1\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}J_2(ax)x^n,$$
where $n>-1$ and $J_2(x)$ is the Bessel function of first kind. Does any one know how to proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

For large  real $z$,
$J_r(z)
= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\left(\cos(z-\frac{r\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})+O(z^{-1})\right)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
J_2(z)
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\left(\cos(z-\pi-\frac{\pi}{4})+O(z^{-1})\right)\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\left(\cos(z-\frac{5\pi}{4})+O(z^{-1})\right)\\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi z}} (\cos(z)+\sin(z))+O(z^{-1})\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\cos(z)+\sin(z))+O(z^{-1})\right)\\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi z}} \left((\cos(z)+\sin(z))+O(z^{-1})\right)\\
\end{array}
$

so,
for large $a$,

$\begin{array}\\
J_2(az)
&= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi az}} \left((\cos(az)+\sin(az))+O((az)^{-1})\right)\\
&= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi az}} (\cos(az)+\sin(az))+O((az)^{-3/2})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
we need to estimate,
where $f$ is $\sin$ or $\cos$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1x^ndx\left(\frac{f(ax)}{\sqrt{ax}}+O(a^{-3/2}x^{-3/2})\right)
&=\int_0^1x^ndx\frac{f(ax)}{\sqrt{ax}}+\int_0^1x^ndxO(a^{-3/2}x^{-3/2})\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^1x^{n-1/2}f(ax)dx+O(\frac1{a^{3/2}}\int_0^1x^{n-3/2}dx)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^1x^{n-1/2}f(ax)dx+O(\frac1{(n-1/2)a^{3/2}})\\
\end{array}
$

By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma,
$\int_0^1x^{n-1/2}f(ax)dx
\to 0
$
like
$\frac1{a}$
for both $\sin$ and $\cos$,
so the overall function
goes to zero like
$\frac1{a^{3/2}}$.